# Call class objects from my xUnit test cases

Tags: c#, xunit, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

What do `databaseCreationResult` and `collectionCreationResult` do in the below code. I am writing unit test cases and would like to know how I can access these two objects in my Facts. Database here is a Cosmos DB Emulator. If someone can show me how I can modify my database by giving a simple example in Facts. I have reached till here

```
[Collection( "Tabulardata collection" )]
public class DataTests
{
    private static readonly string CosmosEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
    private static readonly string EmulatorKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
    private static readonly string DatabaseId = "Recordings";
    private static readonly string RecordingCollection = "testdata";
    string Root = Directory.GetParent( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ).Parent.Parent.FullName;

    private async Task ReadConfigAsync()
    {
        var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
                    new ConnectionPolicy
                    {
                        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                        ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
                    });

            var databaseCreationResult = client.CreateDatabaseAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId }).Result;
            var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
                new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection }).Result;
            var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri( DatabaseId, RecordingCollection, "Test" );
            Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync( docUri );    
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CheckCli()
    {
        await ReadConfigAsync();                   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to test? EF Core? The emulator? The DocumentClient? All of which do not make sense. If you want to test _your_ DataAccess code, mock away the DB, so you can verify correct API calls, produce expected errors on purpose etc.

Comment: ^^ If you want to test integration with a real DB, do not test against the emulator. While the emulator makes an effort to behave like the real thing, it won't always be able to do just that.

Comment: I have to test my emulator. I have certain CLi which runs with actual cosmos Db but going forward I would like to test those CLi first with a emulator. So my first goal is to access the emulator and check with a simple modification ..lets say adding a data in collection and assert the count of items in a collection? Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Just take exactly that sentence and translate it to code. Means: 1. You have a starting point of how the data looks => make it look that way. 2. You have a certain modification to perform. => perform it. 3. You expect the result to look a certain way => Assert that result looks like your expectation. Done. ( Maybe more than one single "Assert" may be neccessary)

Comment: i tried that ..if you see creating DocUri.. But I am not sure how can we do this in Facts. I just want to insert a simplest entry in db and check the count

Comment: Yes, then _do_ it. E.g. by having `ReadConfigAsync` return that count. Then you can assert that it is equal to your expected count. Basic Idea is to 1. Setup 2. Act 3. Assert (4. Clean up). Always the same principle.

Comment: Btw: `var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
                new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } ).Result;` is a No-No. `await` that call. You are in a `async Task` function.

Comment: by calling readConfigAsync() I am able to create database and Collection but docuri gives error saying resource not found. Its actually checking if that data with id Test is present or not. I am looking for code here where I should insert data and then check the count which I am unable to do

Comment: yes did that, removed Result and added await. Thanks

Comment: _"I am looking for code here where I should insert data and then check the count which I am unable to do"_ - Aaaah, I see. You should make that more clear in the question. I thought the question was more general about the testing process.